# Xml Python - not well-formed

Tags: python, xml

I have this code:

```
import requests
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
site = 'test.com'
r = requests.get('http://bar-navig.yandex.ru/u?ver=2&url=http://%s&show=1' % (site))
#print r.text.encode('utf-8')
xmldoc = parseString(r.text.encode('utf-8'))
print xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('tcy')[0].attributes['value'].value
```

So, it works, but if I have in `site`, for example, `'vk.com'` or `'google.ru'`, I have an error: `xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token)`.

How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an encoding issue.  XML is supposed to be ASCII based unless specified otherwise.  This XML source, in particular, specifies that it is encoded as `windows-1251`.

Try this:

```
parseString(r.text.encode('windows-1251'))
```

Then it can be parsed.

The Minidom isn't very clever, otherwise it would be able to figure that out by itself when passed a `unicode` (which doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

I tried using encodings of 'utf-8' and 'utf-16' apart from iso-8859-1 and it did not work (for some of the Indian sites, though I failed to have noticed any non-ascii characters on them). But I switched to Selenium and all solved. Avoiding minidom is not so difficult either as selenium has an interface quite similar to minidom. Cheers!